# Use a user selected file path throughout my code

Tags: python, syntax, global-variables, syntax-error

I have my code:

```
def mnuRead(self, event):
    global fn 

    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)

    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        countrylist = []

        fn = dialog.GetPath()
        fh = open(fn, "r") 
        csv_fh = csv.reader(fh)
        for row in csv_fh:
            countrylist.append(row)
        fh.close()
        for rows in countrylist:
            self.myListCtrl.Append(rows)

def btnHDI(self, event):

    myfile = open(fn, "rb")
    wx.MessageBox(fn)
    countries = []
```

My `mnuRead` method allows the user to open a file of their choice. I want to use the string of this filepath in the`btnHDI` method below.

Setting my `fn` variable to global is giving me a syntax error. How do I use this filepath in other methods?

Answer (score 0):

[`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt) is only used for *declaring* one or more names as being global.

You need to move the assignment of `fn = dialog.GetPath()` to the line below:

```
global fn 
fn = dialog.GetPath()
```

Also, it is a common practice to put global declarations at the start of a function:

```
def mnuRead(self, event):
    global fn
```

That way, they are easily visible.

Comment: In my edited code above, I am still receiving an error saying that 'fn' is an undefined name in my 'btnHDI' method. Why is that?

Comment: @PhilipMcQuitty - Are you somehow calling `btnHDI` before `mnuRead`?  When you call `mnuRead`, `fn` is made global and should be accessible to all other functions.

Comment: @PhilipMcQuitty - Another possibility is that `if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:` evaluates to `False` so that `fn` is never set.

Comment: I don't believe so, mnuRead is a menu option for the user to select the file, then btnHDI is a button that needs to use this file path selected by the user.

Comment: Yeah I am baffled, nothing seems to be working. I really just need the string of the path that the user selects. Is there any type of .get method i'm not aware of?

Comment: @PhilipMcQuitty - I am not familiar with `wx`, so I don't think I can help there.  However, it looks like the functions you posted are methods of a class because they both have a `self` parameter.  If so, why not make the path an attribute of the class?  Then, it will be accessible in all methods.